# Open dialog on ajax success call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am struggling to find a way to open a dialog window after a successfull ajax event. At the moment, I am using jquery .html to insert some html into a div, but what I would like to do is to create a dialog window with html instead of using a standard named div. The reason for this is because the values change so a standard response will not do. Is this possibe?

The div in my sample code; #dialog-message, is just an example. Thanks

jquery+dialog code

```
    //Begin function to submit report form

$(function () {
    $("#frmreport").submit(function () {

        var send = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/sample/admin/frm10010.php",
            data: send,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#confirm_department").hide();
                $(function () {
                    $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            Ok: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
                //alert('You have succesfully submitted your ' 
                //   + msg.dept + ' report. Thank you.');
                //$("#report_result").html("You have succesfully 
                //   submitted your report. Thank you."+"<br /><br />");
                $("#formShow").hide();
                $("#formImage .col_1 li").show();
                $("#frmreport").get(0).reset();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

// End function to submit report form
```

Comment: remove `$(function() {...})` around the `dialog` init for starters :)

Comment: Yes, just replace `"#dialog-message"` with an html string that represents a div.

Comment: @Kevin B I did something like this: var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
               .html('This is a sample dialog! '+msg.dept)

Answer (score 0):

No need to wrap your dialog initialization in a `$(function() {...});` function. This attaches a `ready` event listener to the document, so is not needed since you have everything already wrapped: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Try replacing your `success` callback with :

```
function (msg) {
    $("#confirm_department").hide();
    $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    //alert('You have succesfully submitted your ' + msg.dept + ' report. Thank you.');
    //$("#report_result").html("You have succesfully submitted your report. Thank you."+"<br /><br />");
    $("#formShow").hide();
    $("#formImage .col_1 li").show();
    $("#frmreport").get(0).reset();
}
```

Also, `dialog()` is part of [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/), not the base jQuery library. You'll need to import both libraries for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for input. However i was looking to remove the #dialog-message and use .html instead.